# Problema con bootstrap y diseño responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Estoy realizando un formulario con bootstrap y tengo problemas a la hora de redimensionar las columnas de la grid. Cuando se ven en una pantalla con una resolución grande, se ve bien. Sin embargo, cuando la hago pequeña para adaptarla a tablets o móviles, el diseño no se adapta como espero.

Este es el diseño en una pantalla normal:

[image: Diseño original]

Y este es el diseño cuando hago la pantalla pequeña, simulando la pantalla de un smartphone/tablet:

[image: Diseño erróneo]

Lo que yo querría es que el diseño fuera apilado como en esta imagen (o si los controles no pueden estar al lado del otro, pues que estén debajo, pero que por lo menos sea un diseño agradable a la vista):

[image: Diseño final]

Este es el código del formulario:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"> 
        <div class="m-portlet__body m-portlet--primary" data-portlet="true" m-portlet="true">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Que versión de boostrap estás manejado?

Comment: Hola @fashSharp. La 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualmente el grueso de tu página está dividido en 3 columnas que ocupan cada una de ellas 4 celdas del **grid** de **Bootstrap**. Para conseguir lo que necesitas debes hacer que cada columna pase de medir 4 celdas a 12, para que cada pareja de `<label>` + `<input>` ocupe toda la totalidad de la fila.

Así que lo que yo haría sería cambiar cada una de esas tres columnas `<div class="col-4 col-md-4">` por algo como `<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"> 
        <div class="m-portlet__body m-portlet--primary" data-portlet="true" m-portlet="true">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es mucho más completa que la mia @Ferran Muñoz

Comment: Es perfecto, funciona como un reloj. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en las clases `col-4` de cada uno de los div que contienen el label y el input:

```js
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"> 
        <div class="m-portlet__body m-portlet--primary" data-portlet="true" m-portlet="true">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row" style="display: flex; margin-left: 2px">
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Apellido 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```